Hashem only made things we are inclined to do into aveiras
I have heard reference to a principle in shiurim, and my wife recently reminded me of it when she claims she heard it in a lecture by Rebbetzin Heller, for example. The claim is that Hashem doesn't ban "bad" things that we wouldn't do anyway, nor does He command "good" things we would do anyway.
E.g. women are supposedly not commanded to have children because they would anyway, and it's only men who would need a nudge in that direction. The same goes the other way around - if you see something forbidden and can't understand who would do such a thing, be assured that there are some folk born with a proclivity to it, so it had to be banned. If you can think of a "bad" thing that Hashem didn't ban, and are sure it's not a derivative of something else, then you can be sure that nobody would ever do that.
Is there an actual source for this principle? I've heard it claimed in Chassidus that every sin will eventually be done by someone somewhere, who will do teshuva for it. Not that we can do sins in the first instance (lechatchila), although I haven't seen the source for it in depth.
So, I would like any source, including the one I have heard from Chassidus, that anyone can find on this particular principle, please!

Doesn't Chullin 92B discuss how no one would ever want to eat the sciatic nerve (which has no taste) or blood (which is naturally replulsive to human beings)?

@יהושעק yet God gave us parallels to every forbidden thing which are allowed to us.

Not so sure about women having children anyways. Many do not.

Yehoshua K, the metzius is that people do consume blood.  For example, blood sausage, sausage made largely of solidified blood, is common throughout Europe.  Wikipedia has a lengthy article on the topic.

@יהושעקאִם הַדָּם, שֶׁנַּפְשׁוֹ שֶׁל הָאָדָם קָצָה – מִמֶּנּוּ הַפּוֹרֵשׁ מִמֶּנּוּ מְקַבֵּל שָׂכָר and
רָצָה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לִזְכוּת אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל, לְפִיכָךְ הִרְבָּה לָהֶם תּוֹרָה וּמִצְוֹת

Thanks for finding the exact citations, @Banana!

There are many mitzvos that are logical. Honoring one's parents, setting up a judicial system, are some that come to mind. Almost all non Jewish cultures, civilizations, and modern day countries have some form of laws about these matters. They had no Torah to teach them, but they do these things anyway. These are מצוות שכליות. Also, there are sins that most people have no desire for. Eating insects, drinking blood... are things that most people wouldn't do. Why should the fact that there might be some people who desire these things make a difference for us who do not have such desires?

@Shababnik I think about the food thing 'not' being a desire is because of Judaism spreading throughout the world. In China, many people like eating insects quite a bit. And in Thailand, some Thai's believe drinking pig's blood help increase the likelihood of conception.

"E.g. women are supposedly not commanded to have children because they would anyway, and it's only men who would need a nudge in that direction." Yet many women today do choose to forgo having children, either in dedication to other goals or pursuits, or out of ideology.

Indeed, people can be brainwashed out of anything but anyway, the whole point of this is to find the original source, if it exists, so we don't have to speculate about its meaning and intents

@TegLouis yeah. I know. I was just trying to make it work. A bit of a stretch I know.

The gemoro in makkos brings the braisa. רצה הקבה לזכות את ישראל לפיכך הרבה להם תודה ומצוות Rashi explains that hashem forbade the eating of insects which a person has a natural aversion towards. And would never eat bugs anyway so hashem commanded us, just in order to reward us for it.

Could this be the exception that proves the rule?

So, at most, Rashi doesn't agree with the principle that "Hashem doesn't ban 'bad' things that we wouldn't do anyway". It could be a מחלוקת, and the question is asking for a source that does agree with that principle.
